# MVC Filling a table on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using CodeFirst approach in MVC. I have code that fills up a table,

```
db.Categories.Add(new CategoryViewModel { Title = "Metal" });
db.Categories.Add(new CategoryViewModel { Title = "Pop" }); //etc
```

Is there some place I can put this code that will fill up the table on application startup? Instead of in my controllers that get called multiple times.

Comment: Why would you want to do it in app start? The controller is the correct place to load your data and pass it on to the view. You need to find out why is your controller getting invoked twice.

Comment: Well, if I have the code in the controller and then call it once on page load,  every time that page is loaded it will call this code. I only want to fill this data once because it won't be changed for some time

Comment: So if  you somehow put this code in appstart it will be called only once. But what happens when the page is refreshed? The data would be gone anyway.

Comment: Why would it be gone? The values get stored in my SQL CategoryViewModel table

Comment: ?? I am talking about the view. When you refresh the page, it is obvious that you need to get the values again and render them. Are you expecting the view to remember the values on page refresh?

Comment: I am not talking about the view though. I don't care about the view at this point.

My table is currently empty and I want to add values to it using the above code, instead of typing the values in using SQL Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom database initializer and override the `Seed` method to do your custom record insertions to your tables.

Create a new class inheriting from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`

```
public class MyNiceInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        var categoryList= new List<Category>();

        categoryList.Add(new Category() { Title= "Metal"});
        categoryList.Add(new Category() { Title= "Pop" });

        foreach (var category in categoryList)
            context.Categories.Add(category);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Now in your DbContext class, Pass a new instance of this new custom initializer we created to `Database.SetInitializer` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("YourEFConnStringName")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyNiceInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { set; get; }
    //Other Items goes here...
}
```

When your run your app for the first time and accessing any of the DbSet properties of your Dbcontext, EF Will execute your Custom initializer's seed method where we are inserting some records.  This will not happen every time you run your app/page.

Since we are inheriting from [`DropCreateDataBaseIfModelChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604(v=vs.113).aspx), the seeding will happen every time you change your model(classes) along with the recreation of the db.

Comment: Dropping the database when a model changes wipes all data from tables, I have data in other tables that I would like not to be dropped when model changes for these specific tables. E.g. I let the user upload songs to my website, I don't want these songs being dropped if I change my model down the line. Best solution for this?

Comment: There are other db initialization strategies. Just google for it and you will find it. Use the best one you think suit for your requirement.